# Получение индекса ячейки таблицы по событию Touch на UITableView

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, iphone

Как выявить событие `Touch` на `UITableView` и по этому событию получить индекс ячейки из таблицы (IPhone SDK)?

Что надо, надо просто получить `Touch`-cобытие на `UITableView` и потом по этому событию получить индекс ячейки из таблицы. Сразу хочу сказать, что использование кастомных методов для кастомных ячеек не рассматриваю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ого, ну вы хлопцы устроили тут целый батл :). На самом деле ответ очень прост: он вытекает из делегейт метода, который называется `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}`. Кликаем по видимым ячейкам и получаем нужный индекс - все правильно, на входе дальнейшего выполнения задания возникла потребность добавить на каждую ячейку картинку, попадая в которую, происходит удаление. Хотел создать маленькую область по размерам картинки, в которой тач распознавался бы и происходило бы действие, но я немного ошибся - в результате нашел простое решение. На каждой ячейке создаю кнопочку, но не прикрепляю ей `tag`, а делаю следующее:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Ну и собственно метод или селектор, кому как нравится:

```
(void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:SimpleTable];

    red = [SimpleTable indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

    if (red != nil)
    {   
        rocket = red.row;
        NSLog(@"index = %@ = %i", red, rocket);
    }
}
```

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Тебе придется создасть кастомный `UITableView`, в котором ты должен определить методы

**Responding to Touch Events**

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

Подробнее тут :         [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Это огромный костыль, даже если и высчитывать все так, то лучше использовать UIGectureRecognizer

Comment: Ну Ваше решение вообще не ответ на вопрос. Человек хочет получить Touch-событие. А просто найти выбранную ячейку сможет любой. `UIGestrureRecognizer` работает только на iOS >= 4.0, что вставляет еще больше костылей, чем отлавливать touch-события в кастомной таблице. Поэтому Ваш -1 довольно странен.

Comment: Ну во-первых о платформе не было сказано ни слова, а во-вторых определение кастомной таблицы еще более странное решение. К тому вопрошающему может быть и не нужно совсем имеено тач отлавливать, а просто нужно отловить тычек на ячейку таблицы.

Comment: Ладно Вы на SO не можете понять вопрос, потому что там по-английски пишут. Но тут написано все четко - `Touch-cобытие`. Более того, если Вы в чем-то не уверены, то тем более странно, что Вы сразу меня заминусовали, не разобравшись в сути вопроса.

Comment: Я уверен в том что в данном контексте ваше решение - костыль, вместо реализации кастомной таблицы можно использовать решение которое я предоставил в качестве второго варианта. Давайте не будем холиварить, если я вас сильно обидел свлим минусом, то извините.

Comment: Вы предоставили решение для частного случая, но никак не для общего. Ваше решение написано под Ваш же вопрос - вы думаете, что платформа 4.0 и более и вы думаете, что в вопросе прослеживается вопрос об отловле только tap'ов... Мой же ответ отвечает на поставленный вопрос в общем случае. Но Ваше право. Вы поставили мне -1, получите свой accept и будет у вас 1.7 к. Удачи

Answer (score 1):

Сначала указываете вашей таблице в качестве делегата ваш класс-контроллер, можно через InterfaceBuilder, а можно из кода

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

и в вашем классе-контроллере реализуете метод

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);   // вот в вашем indexPath будет информация об индексе ячейки и об индексе секции
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   //  непосредственно ваша ячейка

}
```

Вариант второй, если нужно именно через тач событие

Создаете в контроллере [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) и задаете ему метод который будет вызван при тапе, этот метод должен быть определен в классе который вы передаете в  качестве target, в нашем случае это self

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableTapped:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

А в обработчике тапа уже вычисляете нужную ячейку

```
- (void)tableTapped:(id)sender{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint tapPoint =  [rec locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapPoint];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
}
```